# how add redirect to oscommerce product page

Tags: redirect, product, cart, oscommerce

I have an oscommerce shopping cart site and I'm trying to set up an automatic redirect with 30-second time-delay from one product page to another product page, and include a message like "this prod. is now replaced by [new catalogue number]. You will be automatically redirected." How do I get into the raw HTML/PHP coding for each product so I can put a redirect meta-tag or javascript coding in? Note: I only want to set up the redirect for a handful of product pages (not all products currently on the site).

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function delayer(){
    window.location = "productpage.php"
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 5000)">
<h2>Prepare to be redirected!</h2>
<p>This page is a time delay redirect, please update your bookmarks to our new 
location!</p>

</body>
</html>​
```

you can use Js redirect look like above

check from here > http://jsfiddle.net/JnUVF/

Comment: thanks for the idea; from the merchant-admin panel, where would I insert this script? I can't seem to get into the <head></head> section of the product page from the admin side of the site and I can't find any individual product-page php/html files to download and manually edit...any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this also works without head section as i try. you can put to product description. if oscommerce dont strip <script type="text/javascript">.....</script> code it should work

Comment: Unfortunately oscommerce stripped the script tags. Ah well, a direct link works for now. Thanks for the info anyways.